# Difference between device_register and driver_register

Tags: c, serial-port, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uart

I am writing a UART driver. I came across the two functions in the chapter 14.Linux Device Model.

```
int device_register(struct device *dev);
int driver_register(struct device_driver *drv);
```

Since UART is a char driver I have dynamically created the major number using (`alloc_chrdev_region)` and added the device to kernel by using `cdevadd()`.

I came across `uart_register_driver()` and `platform_driver_register()` in omap-serial.c.

I could map the `driver_register` with the `platform_driver_register()` but the `uart_register_driver` is mapped with tty related function.Since I am a beginner i do not want to use the tty related functions.

Is `uart_register_driver` related with `device_driver()`?.

Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dino, as per my understanding device_register: is nothing but registering a new device to the system and link which you can go through https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-device-register.html. driver_register: registering a platform driver, this driver supports devices based on the ".name" and ".of_match_table" specified in the platform driver structure. ".name" in structure platform_driver and name in the platform_device should match then only device gets bind to driver and probe function is called. Please go through the link http://lwn.net/Articles/448499/

Answer (score 5):

`driver_register`: Adds this driver to the **bus' list of drivers**.

`device_register`: **Bus' list of drivers** is iterated to find the driver that supports this device and then this device is added to the **bus' list of devices**.