# call to request_mem_region() fails

Tags: c, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uart

The start address 0x4806E000 (UART4 base address) is already present in /proc/iomem with the name omap4-uart.

How to disable the memory regions already allocated ?.

Edit :
Even though request_mem_region is successful the console during booting shows this messages.

```
[    0.758514] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 3 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.760040] omap_uart.0: ttyO0 at MMIO 0x4806a000 (irq = 104) is a OMAP UART0
[    0.760498] omap_uart.1: ttyO1 at MMIO 0x4806c000 (irq = 105) is a OMAP UART1
[    0.760955] omap_uart.2: ttyO2 at MMIO 0x48020000 (irq = 106) is a OMAP UART2
[    1.778808] console [ttyO2] enabled
[    1.782989] omap_uart omap_uart.3: [UART3]: failure [serial_omap_probe]: -22
[    1.790466] omap_uart: probe of omap_uart.3 failed with error -22
```

I think it indicates the kernel is still trying to configure the uart4 instance?
Edit 2: During software reset the while loop enters into infinite loop

```
/* Pad Configuration */
    unsigned int pad_value = 0xFFF8FFF8;
    l = ioread32(pad_map);
    l &= pad_value;
    iowrite32(l,pad_map);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "pad configured\n");


    /* Software reset */

       printk(KERN_ALERT "reset check bit = %x\n",((serial_in(UART_OMAP_SYSC))));
       serial_out(UART_OMAP_SYSC,swreset);
       printk(KERN_ALERT "reset check bit = %x\n",((serial_in(UART_OMAP_SYSC))));
       readval = serial_in(UART_OMAP_SYSS);
       while((readval & 0x01)== 0);
       printk(KERN_ALERT "software reset completed\n");
```

Comment: This error would occur because you have not removed the association of **UART4** and the device driver **omap-serial** (aka **omap4-uart**) in the Device Tree.  *"Why the call to ioremap is not failing ?"* -- Device drivers are trusted code executing in privileged mode.  Not every call & its argument list is validated like syscalls from userland.  The device driver should be well-written, and perform the expected reserve-before-map protocol.

Comment: @sawdust:How to remove the association of UART4 and the device driver omap-serial (aka omap4-uart) in the Device Tree?

Comment: @sawdust:Even after commenting out uart4 instance of DT and in omap-serial.c, baseaddress of uart4 instance is visible in /proc/iomem

Comment: *"Even after commenting out uart4 instance of DT..."* -- Instead of trying to describe what you did, you need to actually show us the code or Device Tree nodes and contents of **/proc/iomem**.  Edit your question with this update information.

Comment: @sawdust:the call succeeded when the No ports in omap-serial.h changed to 3 from 6 along with make menuconfig.Thank you for your help.Need not change anything in DT

Comment: @sawdust:Can you please answer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243494/loop-back-mode-enabling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dino,

How to disable the memory regions already allocated ?.

Solution: what i think is that you can disable UART driver from kernel (menuconfig), build the kernel image and check /proc/iomem, I guess UART4 related instances will be removed.

Note: If using device tree concept then need to disable UART4 node "@uart4" in device tree.

I would like to use it in my driver code with different name. Is it possible?

Solution: In your LKM request for the memory range using request_mem_region with your driver name.

BTW: Why the call to ioremap is not failing ?

Solution: ioremap api will not fail because api does not have check for ex:"driver name" or any other checks.

Comment: Even after configuring using menuconfig, baseaddress of uart4 instance is visible in /proc/iomem

Comment: *"I guess UART4 related instances will be removed"* -- Menuconfig will only configure device drivers, and cannot be used to enable/disable or configure individual devices.  That is what the **Device Tree** (or the deprecated platform board file) is for.

Comment: @sawdust, true menuconfig will not disable/enable individual drivers. I meant for testing purpose not to build the OMAP uart driver as such as static. Since inside uart driver only request for memory range is called, by not building the OMAP uart related driver's, all the uart driver related instance will not be visible under "/proc/iomem".

Comment: @GauthamKantharaju: the call succeeded when the No ports in omap-serial.h changed to 3 from 6 along with make menuconfig.Thank you for your help

Comment: @GauthamKantharaju:Can you please answer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243494/loop-back-mode-enabling)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it's possible to reuse the memory region by other driver. This would make first driver misbehaving. This means that in order to use this memory region by your driver, you should first disable the other driver.

Now it's possible that your `ioremap()` call won't return an error. It's also possible that it will appear to work perfectly fine. This is because AFAIK, the content of `/proc/iomem` does not come from `ioremap()` calls but from `request_mem_region()` calls. It's important to understand what both of them do:

- You should first call `request_mem_region` to claim that your driver is going to use requested memory region (note that this won't do any memory mapping, it will only indicate your will in doing so). In case of your device, some driver already did this so it may use this region when needed. It's possible, however, that it didn't call `ioremap()` immediately after claiming the region but will do this on demand.
- If above call succeeded, you may be sure that no other driver is going to use this region. This means you are free to call `ioremap()` and `iounmap()` on this region whenever you want.

Technically it's possible to do only 2nd thing and skip using `request_mem_region` but this way your driver would have to keep memory mapped all times just to indicate that you may use it in future. So you should be nice and always reserve the region first.

Comment: Is it possible to remove only UART4 instances from the driver which was installed prior my driver installation? I am writing a device driver for uart4 instance of omap-4460 pandaboard.is there any alternate way?

Comment: @Dino: I don't know this driver but it's rather unusual to write a driver that has an option to disable itself without unloading. So if this driver is installed as a module, you should just unload the module. If it's compiled in, you may be out of luck and recompilation may be needed. This shouldn't be weird for you, after all you want to create a driver of a piece of hardware that already has a driver installed.

Comment: :Thanks for your time.this is the [code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c?v=3.4).In my case driver is compiled and is configured on booting.So modifying driver code may help.

Comment: @Dino: Instead of changing the driver you should configure your kernel (i.e. with `make menuconfig`) to compile this driver as a module or not to compile it at all. `SERIAL_OMAP` is an option for this driver, I believe.

Comment: :Yeah I will try that method and check it out

Comment: :I had configured the kernel using `make menuconfig`.But still the base address is visible in /proc/iomem

Comment: @Dino: And of course you did kernel recompilation, etc? Either you did something wrong or it's some other driver that is reserving this region.

Comment: Yes I did recompilation using `make uImage`.But still there is no effect.I commented out uart4 instanced in DT and in omap-serial.c.Again there is no change.

Comment: @Dino, as I already wrote in my previous comment, it seems that it's different driver than we thought, not `SERIAL_OMAP`. It's hard to help you when we don't know the details. Look in `dmesg` output and try to find anything about uart there, this may give you a clue.

Comment: :the call succeeded when the No ports in omap-serial.h changed to 3 from 6 along with make menuconfig.Thank you for your help

Comment: @Dino: I'm glad that you managed to fix this but as you can clearly see, you must have done something wrong when disabling your driver before. If changing number of requested ports worked then disabling the driver should work too. But that's not really that important since it's working as it is now.

Comment: :But now the issue is,when I write certain value to particular register address(virtual address obtained from io_remap)the read value is different from what is written.

Comment: @Dino: That issue is completely unrelated to this question. Also, it's hard to tell if this is an issue. It's an I/O register, not a memory so it's possible that this behaviour is expected.

Comment: :Yeah But the loop for sw reset or for LSR flag enters into infinite value.I will put some section of the code in the question.Please check it out.

Comment: @Dino: Once again, I believe the best thing to do is to disable omap_uart altogether if you are going to mess up with I/O ports related to UART.

Comment: But the UART1 instance is used for the console.So disabling entire omap_uart will be difficult.